# What are WordPress Current Security Issues in 2017?

Tags: security

I just set up basic WordPress on a server.

My school assignment is to secure WordPress to the best of my ability. I'm just a student so I don't have practice with real world attacks so I don't know really how potentially WordPress could be exploited. So I was wondering what are the current vulnerabilities and where can I look on the knowledge to fix some of them.

Comment: WordPress never keeps any known `vulnerabilities` unfixed. However, there are more to `security` than just fixing `vulnerabilities`. Read this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

Comment: Nice school assignment :) What you have been taught about security in general ? I assume your teacher has talk about security topics, right?

Comment: @Laxmana mostly just about types of attacks and how they are caused and how they are prevented. Safe practices and the like. I'd assume something as big as wordpress has cracked down on most things and would probably be hard to exploit by now.

Comment: Yes it would be very hard to exploit the WordPress Core imo. A lot of security issues arise from plugins or themes that misuse the WordPress Core functionality. You can read [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) and [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) about data sanitation and data escaping. Another thing you can do is to take a previous version of WordPress with a know security issue (you can search the version changelog) and try to exploit it. I don't know if this scenario is permitted in your assignment.